# Is there any function that calculates Gini Index for CART(Decision Tree Algorithm) in R?

Tags: r, cart, gini

In using CART, 
I would like to select primary attributes from whole attributes using Gini index.

But I couldn't find any functions or packages containing it.

If there are any functions or packages that calculates Gini index, Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

If you fit a CART model using the `rpart` function from `library(rpart)` there is an option to specify the splitting criteria as either the Gini coefficient or the information statistic.

The syntax is:

```
rpart(y~x+z, data=df, parms=list(split='gini'))
```

In fact, 'gini' is the default so if you just use the `rpart` function it will use the gini coefficient anyway. For more you can see the pdf introduction to the method and the package [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rpart/vignettes/longintro.pdf).

If I misunderstood what you are using this for, and you just want functions that compute gini coefficients, you can look at the package `ineq`, including the function `ineq()` which will compute a variety of inequality scores for you. Documentation is [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ineq/ineq.pdf).